# How can I generate CIL from X++ in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, cil, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

Is it possible to generate CIL (either incremental or full) from within X++ code or the command line?

My problem is that I want to import a model or xpo into AX, and I need the CIL to be generated automatically. This is for automated testing we are doing-- so, I can't use the UI like you normally would to generate the incremental or full CIL

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Passing the startupcmd parameter to the AX client causes it to run the corresponding SysStartupCmd class. There's one called SysStartupCmdCompileIL that does a CIL compile.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe" \\server\share\yourconfigfile.axc -startupcmd=CompileIL
```

Answer (score 2):

The code the command line calls, from Jay's post, if you want it in X++ is as follows:

```
try
{
    SysCompileIL::generateIL(); 
}
catch
{
    SysCompileIL::mergeAssemblyFile();
    throw Exception::Error;
}
SysCompileIL::mergeAssemblyFile();
```